# Using iframes in the place of proper 'master pages'

Tags: html, iframe, master-pages

I've been told I have to make a 100% HTML CSS Javascript site for a project at school.  I'm used to the master pages of asp.net and I'm worried about how I'm going to do a huge website without the use of them.

After thinking about it for a while, I came up with what I think is an ok solution.  Using iframes...

Would it be safe to make one page that has an iframe instead of a content area to connect to other pages to make it appear as if we used a master page?

It seems kind of hacked up so, is there a better way?  Is there any software (hopefully free) that provides a decent system of master pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a js-based template engine, such as [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

Answer (score 1):

You could just dreamweaver and use dreamweaver templates.

Answer (score 1):

[Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) includes the [ttree](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/tools/ttree.html) utility, which will do what you want. You can build the site from templates to get plain, static HTML documents. Since this takes place at build time, you do not need anything like ASP / PHP / Perl / etc on the server at runtime.